# Fold text in markdown used to work on Jupyter does not work on GitHub

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I used the fold text in the markdown to write descriptions of my code and it works fine on Jupyter but when the file is uploaded on GitHub, the fold text does not work and show the text expanded. Does anyone know how to fix the issue? I copied the markdown code for reference. Thank you!

< Jupyter >
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4Ake.png)

```
### 1-2. Research for brainstorming, methodology, platforms for the data acquisition <br>
<details>
  <summary>✚ <b><i>1-2-1. Fundamental Analysis</i></b>  (Click to see details)</summary>
Fundamental Analysis is a method of determining a stock's real or "fair market" value by examining related economic and financial factors. The financial ratios of a firm can infer the financial health (or fair market value) of the organization. If the fair market value (intrinsic value or true value) is higher than the market price, the stock is deemed undervalued, and a buy recommendation is given. On the other hand, if the fair market value is lower than the market price, the stock is deemed overvalued, and the recommendation might be not to buy or to sell if the stock is held. We used 17 financial ratios as the indicators to assess stocks for an investment. They also helped to downsize the number of stocks in healthcare for the portfolio optimization modeling. <br>
</details>
<br>
```

< Uploaded and shown on GitHub >
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGdg7.png)

```
 "### 1-2. Research for brainstorming, methodology, platforms for the data acquisition <br>\n",
    "<details>\n",
    "<summary>✚ <b><i>1-2-1. Fundamental Analysis</i></b>  (Click to see details)</summary>\n",
    "\n",
    "Fundamental Analysis is a method of determining a stock's real or \"fair market\" value by examining related economic and financial factors. The financial ratios of a firm can infer the financial health (or fair market value) of the organization. If the fair market value (intrinsic value or true value) is higher than the market price, the stock is deemed undervalued, and a buy recommendation is given. On the other hand, if the fair market value is lower than the market price, the stock is deemed overvalued, and the recommendation might be not to buy or to sell if the stock is held. We used 17 financial ratios as the indicators to assess stocks for an investment. They also helped to downsize the number of stocks in healthcare for the portfolio optimization modeling. <br>\n",
 "\n",
    "</details>\n",
    "<br>\n",
    "\n",
    "\n",
    "\n",
    "<details>\n",
```

I tried to edit it on GitHub and the file could not be opened afterwards. I'm not sure how to fix the fold issue on GitHub.

Comment: It seems you put what gets rendered as text here. I'm curious as to what the markdown code you put in the cells is? I would prefer to see an example of that here as well, preferably pasted into a code block (not as you did with the text rednering you put above). I suspect I know; however, it would help to be sure and **importantly serve as a guidepost for others that may be following in your footsteps** dealing with issues on StackOverflow. I like to make that seem less burdernsome with a reminder that the one following in your footsteps may be "future you" several months from now.

Comment: In this case, if you had an example that was public that would have been nice to share a link to it in your original post, too. If you don't have a public example yourself, sometimes using another place using the same feature is helpful. Sharing a link to example where it is would eliminate the need for actual putting markdown code block here, although in this case a succinct example is nice and saves those trying to helping you some clicks.

Comment: @Wayne Thank you for your help! I put what gets rendered as text so it did not show the original markdown code I wrote. Sorry for the confusion. I used details and summary tags to use fold text. Below is the example markdown code I used.

Comment: ```
### 1-2. Research for brainstorming, methodology, platforms for the data acquisition <br>
<details>
  <summary>✚ <b><i>1-2-1. Fundamental Analysis</i></b>  (Click to see details)</summary>
Fundamental Analysis is a method of determining a stock's real or "fair market" value by examining related economic and financial factors. The financial ratios of a firm can infer the financial health (or fair market value) of the organization.  <br>
</details>
<br>
```

Comment: Good. That's what I figured you were using and so my answer is pertinent then.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing it right 

Comment: If you mean, using 'code blocks'. In this case you are close. Only inline code blocks work in comments though. No biggie. It is clear now. It is something I can add to my ever growing list of why users of Jupyter and GitHub still need to be aware of nbviewer. GitHub used to not try to render notebooks that had more than a few cells of content and so Jupyter users found out quickly about the shortcomings and were familiar with nbviewer early on. As GitHub has improved the preview, new users fail to realize there's nbviewer and it is what they've been seeking.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using `details` and `summary` tags to make collapsible /toggleable section (drop-down section)? (See
[A collapsible section containing markdown](https://gist.github.com/pierrejoubert73/902cc94d79424356a8d20be2b382e1ab)). Maybe not though? Or maybe you added the 'plus symbol'? It would be nice if you updated your post with an example markdown code.

---

As GitHub has improved support for rendering Jupyter notebooks on its site especially over the last couple of years, a lot of new users have come to think the GitHub's rendering is what they have to use. GitHub is just doing that as a convenience to developers and **you should only view GitHub's rendering as a sometimes helpful preview**.

The Jupyter community offers a solution to view and share notebooks that is devoid of the GitHub cruft that is off-putting to non-programmers, and that **importantly, has many more features supported**. It is [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/).

You'll see others use it to share 'static' views of Jupyter notebook files with others. For example, go [here](https://clustergrammer.readthedocs.io/#clustergrammer2) and click on the 'nbviewer' badge on the right, just under 'Clustergrammer2' heading.   Conveniently this doesn't involve you hosting your notebook in any place other than GitHub or elsewhere on the web. You just point the site at your GitHub file. You can use the URL generated in the form at [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/) all over and it will just direct the nbviewer site to get your content from GitHub or elsewhere. For GitHub, the pattern of the URL can be discerned by examining a few example. It really just changes the start of GitHub's own URL. And once you are familiar with the pattern of the URLs, you can draft the nbviewer variations from the GitHub ones without using the form.

##### What features and ablities does nbviewer support that GitHub doesn't?

Several.

You've found one. There are many others. One big one that comes up is that Javascript-based elements such as some widgets and especially Plotly code remain interactive even in this 'static' rendering.

Beyond that the cleaner interface makes it much better for sharing with those that don't use GitHub. The nbviewer rendering has a link to the GitHub page for it in the upper right corner and so that connection is there for the more advanced users to follow if they want.

##### Example for this ability, with a Caveat

I recently made an `.ipynb` file that uses this feature and is hosted on GitHub.
You can go to [here to view it in nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/mitcom-binder/blob/main/notebooks/DEMO_extract_gene_list_from_screen_copied_MitCOM_data.ipynb). To find the toggle-able text, search 'Click here to reveal the large image'. You'll see if you click on the text it reveals an image I was using the feature to hide. **This also brings me to an unfortunate caveat for this particular ability.**

**Caveat: it presently nay imperfect for this ability.**
The toggle triangle that comes up when you view it in a classic Jupyter notebook (version 7.0.1) and JupyterLab (versions 3.4.8 and 4.0.3) presently doesn't show in or nbviewer. I only noticed this recently. I suspect it will be improved [as more of the underlying tech for both the document-oriented interface, presently the 'classic' interface, and JupyterLab moves towards using JupyterLab's tech soon](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/79-notebook-v7/notebook-v7.html) and features those using the classic notebook interface have come to rely on need to get supported better in JupyterLab. (If it gets rectified in JupyterLab then that may solve it in nbviewer or at least highlight the need for a solution there, too.) I'll try to keep my eyes out for an issue report about this and update this post with it. That way maybe others can chime in that this ability is important and it will get some attention sooner, rather than later.