# When I use <details></details> in Jupyter Notebook with a summary (markdown), the arrow doesn't show

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, markdown

When I click to the side, the summary still shows

[image: ![enter image description here]
[image]

Comment: Which version are you using? Jupyter Notebook V7 or NbClassic? Other? Those details are necessary in your post. I just tried it in Jupyter Notebook V 7.0.1 and JupyterLab 3.4.8 and 4.0.3 and the arrow shows in all those. FWIW I like what Jen used with the bold plus symbol [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75685895/fold-text-in-markdown-used-to-work-on-jupyter-does-not-work-on-github?noredirect=1#comment133525866_75685895). Might suffice as a work around for now?