# End of line disappears on GitHub in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Saving a copy of my Jupyter notebook from Colab to my GitHub repo, the end of line characters disappear from the code blocks.
Code block on Colab:

[image]

Code block on GitHub:

[image]

In the ipynb file there are '\n' characters:

[image]

This only happens recently, I was able to use Colab and GitHub together without problems, few weeks ago.
Have you any idea to solve it? I have Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop.

UPDATE:
Here you can find an ipynb file with missing EOL: https://github.com/OSGeoLabBp/tutorials/blob/master/english/data_processing/lessons/commandlineparameters.ipynb

Comment: You are using a quick preview tool by a third party & expecting it to render your `.ipynb` file correctly. Since it is on GitHub, provide the link or post a toy example and provide the link. (Or at least provide the code, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77969756/8508004) for a slightly better post where the OP at least included the code.)Then I could post your code looking fine **probably**. Please read & follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The guide specifically covers under 'Help others reproduce the problem' ...

Comment: <continued> how to provide the code as code text. I suspect you have the same issue as [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77969756/8508004) and it will be fixed using the Jupyter-provided nbviewer; however, because you provide no code or links in your post, I cannot conclusively tell if that is the case. I think the screengrab off GitHub I share in the bottom of [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77970720/8508004) may also be not respecting line endings and so that is why I say it may be the same.

Comment: Also, any chance you updated your browser? There was [an issue with line ending that was particular to browsers a few months ago](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/inline-latex-errors/22471/13?u=fomightez). Could that be related to yours? I only ask because you say, "This only happens recently, I was able to use Colab and GitHub together without problems, few weeks ago."

Comment: @Wayne sample page link added to the end of the question.

Comment: @Wayne I use firefox 122.0.1 and chromium 121.0.6167.160 on Ubuntu 22.04 and the view on github is the same.

Comment: Thanks for that. I think confusing the current matter is that there was a browser issue with line endings that I think was mainly Windows and so sorting with is a new vs recent endings will be important to understanding all this.

Comment: This is happening to a lot of users. For example, my entire course stopped rendering correctly on github. This is very annoying, considering the (unchanged) content was working fine until a week ago! https://github.com/USCBiostats/PM520

Comment: GitHub has fixed this now, see [here](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/4365#issuecomment-1943920639). nbviewer will still be more feature-rich.

Comment: Yes, @wayne, it was fixed by GitHub. Thanks your efforts.