# On GitHub, Jupyter notebook code (in cell) wrongly displayed as a long string instead of separate lines

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook

On GitHub website, code in some of my Jupyter notebooks recently began to display weirdly.

Specifically, in a code cell, code lines are displayed as a long string instead of seperate lines.

For example, https://github.com/kanru-wang/Graph_Neural_Network/blob/main/Node_Classification_Simple.ipynb

and also https://github.com/kanru-wang/Udemy_GAN_and_Diffusion_models/blob/main/CelebA_WGAN.ipynb

I remember a few months ago these Jupyter notebooks were displayed properly, and I haven't made changes since then.

I have tried a few web browsers and saw the same issue.

I have checked the underlying JSON files of the affected Jupyter notebooks, but the newline characters "\n" are in place, and the formatting seems correct.

Thank you.

=============== EDIT =================

Got a reply from the GitHub community,

> There have been occasional reports of GitHub rendering issues that can
> cause Jupyter notebook code to display incorrectly. This is usually a
> temporary issue that is resolved by GitHub within a short period.

Comment: This has already been asked and initially addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77976097/8508004). In short, you should not be relying on GitHub's quick preview. There is a Jupyter-provided solution via nbviewer. Your GitHub hosted content rendered via there: [#1](https://nbviewer.org/github/kanru-wang/Graph_Neural_Network/blob/main/Node_Classification_Simple.ipynb) and [#2](https://nbviewer.org/github/kanru-wang/Graph_Neural_Network/blob/main/Node_Classification_Simple.ipynb). nbviewer is much more feature-rich than GitHub's quick preview & so it is best you move to using that ...

Comment: <continued> regularly, even if GitHub fixes this issue they recently introduced.

Comment: GitHub has fixed this now, see [here](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/4365#issuecomment-1943920639). nbviewer will still be more feature-rich.

Comment: Thanks Wayne. I also got a reply from github community, "There have been occasional reports of GitHub rendering issues that can cause Jupyter notebook code to display incorrectly. This is usually a temporary issue that is resolved by GitHub within a short period."