# Jupyter notebook not rendering properly on GitHub, with no line breaks in code

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, rendering

GitHub can directly render Jupyter notebooks properly. For example, [this page](https://github.com/bopopescu/Program-Demo/blob/5476bf3afc01cc6aa5c72d655f28a247446b7cc6/jupyter_notebooks_analysis/notebooks/0_nb_metadata_download.ipynb) renders very nicely.

However, [this page](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Pearl/blob/main/pearl/tutorials/single_item_recommender_system_example/demo.ipynb), or [this page](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Pearl/blob/main/pearl/tutorials/frozen_lake/demo.ipynb), do not. The code lines are all jumbled together without the proper line breaks.

The second one, for example, has a cell rendered thus:

[image]

Looking at their code (respectively [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Pearl/blob/main/pearl/tutorials/single_item_recommender_system_example/demo.ipynb?short_path=9133176) and [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Pearl/blob/main/pearl/tutorials/frozen_lake/demo.ipynb?short_path=2773cee)), they seem correct, and the code lines are properly finished with `\n`.

What explains the incorrect rendering?

Comment: This has already been covered [here in 'On GitHub, Jupyter notebook code (in cell) wrongly displayed as a long string instead of separate lines'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77982399/8508004) and [here in 'End of line disappears on GitHub in Jupyter notebooks'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77976097/8508004), and also a bit buried as a component of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77970720/8508004). Concisely, you should in general always be using nbviewer, the Jupyter-provided solution for viewing notebooks. It pre-dated the initially very limited GitHub rendering and remains much more ...

Comment: <continued> full-featured and rich than the still limited abilities of the quick preview for developers provided by GitHub. You can point nbviewer at anything accessible on the internet. It has much less cruft around it and remains a better choice for sharing with non-developer stakeholders. [nbsanity](https://nbsanity.com/) was proposed as better than it for mobile rendering, yet nbviewer works on mobile devices, too.

Comment: You examples looking fine at nbviewer: [#1 here](https://nbviewer.org/github/facebookresearch/Pearl/blob/main/pearl/tutorials/single_item_recommender_system_example/demo.ipynb) and [#2 here](https://nbviewer.org/github/facebookresearch/Pearl/blob/main/pearl/tutorials/frozen_lake/demo.ipynb). You'll note upon examination that the URLs for the GitHub-hosted pages follow a standard pattern so that you can skip entering the source URLs in the form at [the main nbviewer page](https://nbviewer.org/) if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks. What is the best way you recommend to redirect people looking at the file on GitHub to nbviewer? Seems like adding the nbviewer link to the top of the notebook is the easiest even though not ideal.

Comment: My best advice is to share the nbviewer-based link with others and use it in your documentation. You can put a badge at the top like is commonly done on the of READMEs, too. See [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbviewer/issues/714#issuecomment-662148198). In the past when GitHub would readily acknowledge their limited rendering as they wouldn't try to even render anything over 100kb, they encouraged nbviewer use with a link to it there. That insured new users learned about nbviewer soon in their journey. Alas, it isn't the current situation.